# Eclipse Javascript 'Class' Outline

Tags: javascript, eclipse, outline

Using Eclipse Oxygen running on OSX.
I have several files with object structures mimicing classes using prototype in the standard way:

```
function MyClass(args) {
  this.testconstant = 'ctrl';
  MyClass.prototype.start = function () {//initialises BaseCtrl - child objects must also call their own boot
  }  
}
```

however Eclipse simply shows the outline as:

```
o MyClass(args)
```

Is there a plugin or something that addresses this - it appears to be a long running issue that is still not fixed. I've set up as a new Javascript project.

Comment: It would have to execute the code to figure out what it's doing. JavaScript doesn't really have "classes" the way other languages do; it's really a distinct concept.

Comment: Absolutely, hence me quoting the word class to indicate the fact its not really. I am aware its very conceptually different but its a structure that works very similarly in code that then uses it. I can see no reason why it would need to execute anything. Indeed other IDEs such as Netbeans show the structure.

Comment: Well, it could *guess*, but constructor functions can call other functions and really do anything. Figuring out what the resulting object *really* looks like would require executing a call to the constructor (somehow guessing the parameters to pass, another hard problem) or at the very least a decent static analysis (which would basically be the "guess"). Now, if you use ES2015 `class` syntax, Eclipse might understand that.

Comment: ES2015 looks promising and is syntactically better and clearer to write and read. It does as you advise also break down better in Eclipse to precisely what I need. I'll need to do some testing but please change what you commented as an answer while I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, an IDE really can't accurately tell you what objects in a "class" look like in JavaScript because there's really no such thing as a "class". Objects are dynamically constructed by code, and it's code that can do absolutely anything. It can, for example, randomly create an object with randomly-named properties on each invocation. That sounds contrived, but such things may prove useful to somebody because the flexibility is there.

A less contrived example would be a constructor that accepts some number of parameters, and the values of those parameters determine what properties are initialized on the constructed object.

Thus, to really get it right, an IDE would have to execute the constructor code, and it would have to know what parameters to pass, and it would somehow have to deal with the fact that a single constructor can construct an infinite variety of differently "shaped" objects. Thus, in practical terms, the best it  could do would be to show you what's on the prototype object.

Now, in ES2015 there's a `class` declaration syntax that brings a little order to the chaos, and an IDE could easily leverage that to enhance the editing experience. Not a whole lot different than just figuring out what the prototype looks like, but probably somewhat easier since the issue of where the prototype comes from is pretty open-ended too.

Note that I have no idea how in particular Eclipse or any other IDE deals with this.